# mapping two commands in one shortcut

Tags: gvim, windows

I am using gvim 9.0.1047 on Windows 10

I added the following to my vimrc so I can run the sas program I am working on and open the log file without leaving vim:

```
map <F12> :!"C:\Program Files\SASHome\SASFoundation\9.4\sas.exe" % -CONFIG "C:\Program Files\SASHome\SASFoundation\9.4\nls\en\SASV9.CFG" -nosplash -icon -log %<.log -print %<.lst<CR> & :e %<.log<CR>
```

It works fine, but it puts a hash (#) in the program at the front of the line where the cursor lies when I hit f12

I can't understand why. Thanks for any help

EDIT: I saw the same problem with simpler mapping eg,

```
map <F8> :set guifont=Consolas:h12:cANSI:qDRAFT<CR> & :set numberwidth=2<CR>
```

ie this also produces the #. At the bottom here: https://vim.fandom.com/wiki/Mapping_keys_in_Vim_-_Tutorial_(Part_2), they suggest this should be

```
map <F8> :set guifont=Consolas:h12:cANSI:qDRAFT<CR> \| set numberwidth=2<CR>
```

this solves it ie no # appears, but the second setting is not implemented when i write it like this. I wonder how to get any mapping like this where you want to do 2 things, in the above case i want to reduce the font size and narrow the left margin (to get the output to fit on the screen)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't manage to reproduce your problem since I don't have `sas.exe`

I would do:

```
nnoremap <F12> :execute '!"C:\Program Files\SASHome\SASFoundation\9.4\sas.exe"' expand('%') '-CONFIG "C:\Program Files\SASHome\SASFoundation\9.4\nls\en\SASV9.CFG" -nosplash -icon -log' expand('%<') . '.log' '-print' expand('%<') . '.lst' \| e %<.log<CR>
```

I have:

- Used `execute` to be able to have a sequence of command.
- Used `'` to avoid the backslash (`\`) are interpreted by Vim the wrong way
- Used `|` to separate the two commands
- Used `expand` to build the argument of your command line

Comment: thanks a lot for this. It works. A couple minor things: 1) it throws errors with the ':e %<.log<CR>' bit, but that's ok, i will use another fn key to open and scan the log, 2) i had to add <CR><CR> to the end, I'm not sure why

Comment: Thanks for the feedback :-) If the solution solves your problem I'll be glad if you could validate it using the green v button next to the voting arrow buttons.

Comment: actually the problem has evolved :) i'll edit the question to clarify

Comment: I forgot to escape the `|`. To solve the problem add only one `<CR>` at the end of the command and skip the one in the middle of the command.

Comment: excellent, that works, many thanks!

Comment: Thanks for the feedback ;-)